# Is it possible to take back the control from an MITM in progress?

Tags: network, man-in-the-middle

I heard that MITM also involves DNS poisoning, which basically tells the Net
to take a different route than it was supposed to go..

(I'm not sure if my interpretation is correct..)

Given there is an MITM attack happening towards my computer, would it be
possible to reverse poison, and cut the MITM out ?

Comment: There are several mechanisms that may be sufficient to mount a MITM attack: ARP poisoning, an eavesdropping ISP, DNS spoofing, etc. If you are only interested in DNS spoofing attacks, it may be helpful to make that more clear in the title and question body.

Comment: I mean ANY means to cut out the middleman..
No matter how they try and get in the middle..
They worm themselves in your connection, so
it must stand to reason that they can be
wormed out again right ?

It's not a hard question..it's a hard answer..one that really needs answering..

Comment: I think listing defenses against every possible way an MITM attack can occur is probably too broad for a Stack Exchange answer. If you wanted to address one specific attack vector (like DNS poisoning) then that would probably be appropriately narrow. "Man in the Middle" describes a vulnerable state; the term does not imply *how* a system was put in that vulnerable state. Answers about practical defense measures will vary depending on the practical attack measures used to execute the attack.

Comment: A virus I can cope with and such, but this is an attack that doesn't ACTUALLY involve my system, but happens to my connection on the Net..

Comment: Well..let me ask the first answer then..How many ways can an MITM happen to a an HTTPS connection that was HTTPS from the start ?

Comment: Perhaps it might help if you explain why you think there is a man in the middle. It might not be DNS poisoning after all, but simply an edited hosts file.

Answer (score 2):

When you are under an MITM attack, typically the attacker has complete control of part of the link between you and your intended destination. For this reason, it is usually difficult to "bypass" MITM, if done correctly, because the attacker is fully in control of your traffic and free to direct it to wherever he pleases. The attacker can basically just ignore all routing protocol, and direct *all* of your traffic to the attacker's server, regardless of intended destination.

Also, an MITM does not have to involve someone "worming their way in". Anyone who controls a router or cable link between you and your destination can easily MITM because they *already* control your Internet traffic. Whenever you communicate through the Internet, your traffic probably goes through at least a dozen routers owned by various Internet companies before it reaches its destination. You can see this for yourself if you run a `traceroute` command.

If any one of those router operators decide that they want to do something malicious, they can easily reconfigure their routers to send your traffic somewhere else, rather than follow routing protocol and forwarding it on to the next router.

It is, however, possible to detect that a MITM is occurring by utilizing public key cryptography combined with a certificate system to verify the identity of the person you are communicating with, as HTTPS does. But once you detect a MITM, there's usually not much you can do about it - your options are basically either to immediately stop what you're doing, or attempt to establish an encrypted VPN tunnel to a trusted location and hope that the attacker does not notice and block your VPN.

If you want to truly "bypass" the MITM, you would have to get your traffic to take another route to the destination, one that goes around the attacker. In some situations, that's impossible - for example, if the attacker is your ISP, then there is literally no other route your traffic can take because your ISP is your sole link to the Internet. But even if there is an alternative route, it is still difficult because you don't really have any control of how your traffic is routed. It would be nice if you could tell all the routers handling your traffic, "Hey, I think Router XXX is doing MITM, could you please not send any of my traffic there? Thanks." But since there is no easy way to do that, you are basically at the mercy of the routers' decisions. If you are lucky, perhaps a benevolent router operator will notice that a neighboring router is acting funny and stop sending traffic there, but that's pretty hit-or-miss.

Oftentimes though, the attacker is not someone who is "naturally" between you and your destination, but is instead on your local network and playing tricks on the LAN (like ARP spoofing, or DNS poisoning) to get your computer to send traffic to a place where it would not normally send it. This is where it gets murkier, and where the answer is going to depend on both the technique used and the amount of control you have over the network you're on. For example, if you are on your home WiFi network and the attacker manages to connect to your WiFi to do MITM, then it's easy -  just change your WiFi password and boot the attacker off your network. But if it's at a public place, then obviously it will be more difficult.

Answer (score -1):

From your post I understand that you are talking about ARP poisoning MITM attack. After ARP poisoning done , attacker simply changes the responses of your DNS request with his desired input. If you can detect the malicious ARP responses then you can simply switch to static ARP, (if you know the gateway of your network) then you can cut the attack.

Comment: I'm not sure how you are getting ARP poisoning from the question. You do not need ARP poisoning to perform DNS poisoning.

Comment: you are right my mistake :D